# Why this code is using an Async method?

Tags: c#, async-await

I was reading this [article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/identity?view=aspnetcore-2.1&tabs=visual-studio%2Caspnetcore2x) on Microsoft Identity when I came across this code:

```
// POST: /Account/Register
[HttpPost]
[AllowAnonymous]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public async Task<IActionResult> Register(RegisterViewModel model)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        var user = new ApplicationUser { UserName = model.Email, Email = model.Email };
        var result = await _userManager.CreateAsync(user, model.Password);
        if (result.Succeeded) {
       //.. REDUCTED .. //
       }
}
```

I was wondering why this code is using `CreateAsync` and awaits for it, instead of using a sync method?
Right now, this blocks until `CreateAsync` returns, so why not using a sync method? What's the difference, advantage or reason behind using an async method and awaiting it?
Thanks

Comment: "Right now, this blocks until `CreateAsync` returns" <-- it doesn't, does it? The `await` operator is there, so `CreateAsync` should be run asynchronously/

Comment: @Sweeper Doesn't it read like this: Await until this function returns, then proceed to the next line? If I am wrong here then that explains everything.

Comment: Also I/O operations should preferably be async/await. Interacting with database, files etc should be async

Comment: @Sweeper-  `await` doesn't cause anything to run asynchronously. You hand `await` *something* that will later produce a result, but how that activity *started* is nothing to do with `await`. In this case, it's an implementation detail *within* `CreateAsync` of how it ended up producing a `Task` that will later be completed.

Comment: For I/O-bound code, you await an operation which returns a Task or Task<T> inside of an async method. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/async#basic-overview-of-the-asynchronous-model

Comment: With `await` you let the current thread be used elsewhere until the operation is completed.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The whole point of `async` and `await` are to be able to say "I can make no useful progress here, so perhaps the thread that I'm using could be found some useful work to do elsewhere."

It's true that both versions (what you've shown, and the potential synch one) "block", but one of them (the `async` version) does so without *tying up a thread doing nothing useful*. When the awaitable has finished its work, a suitable thread will be found (in this context, any thread pool thread is suitable) to *resume* the work of processing the request.